# The last two line of code unable two understand

Tags: javascript

```
function makeArmy () {
  let shooters = [];
  let i = 0;

  while (i < 10) {
    let shooter = function() {
    console.log(i);
  };

  shooters.push(shooter);
  i++
 }

 return shooters;
}

let army = makeArmy();
army[0]();
army[5]();
```

i didnt understand this what-why this need for output

```
army[0](); 
army[5]();
i know [0 and 5 are index numbers]
```

im not understaning why this army is calling two times and why we need to call this for output?

Comment: It just won't work, I is a local variable declared in makeArmy, then inside another function which is crated in the while loop it references I, which will not be what you think then shooter is called.  You need to pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: army is callable (thus the round brackets) because it is an array of functions (closures) that you can call and those closures then will execute the print statement.

Comment: What part of those calls are wondering about? Why are you calling army[0]() and army[5]()? Are you trying to do something with their values? We need to know what you're having trouble understanding before we can give any helpful answers. Are you confused as to why you get 10 back for both armies?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1754221/lenny
bt why that index number passed? even if we put any number <10 it shows the same output

Comment: `army[0]` os first element of army array. That element is typeof function, you run function with parentheses `()`. You can write it like `let armyFunc0 = army[0]; armyFunc0();`

Comment: so each item in the array (the 0th for index 0, the 5th for index 5th) is a different closure. But they all refer to the i-variable when they were created. Because the while loop has finished, i will be the maximum index and thus 10.

Comment: so why need to call army[0](); 
army[5](); two times?

Comment: This cannot be answered by the comunity because there is no reason. It completely depends on you what you want to do with those shooters in your army ;)

Comment: okay so last- what that code doing there? except index number.

Comment: @NewJS you can see what they do - each one prints a number. They call the function you defined in your makeArmy method's while loop - function() {
console.log(i);
};. Each time you call any index on that army array, you're calling that function, which writes the number for the shooter to the console.

Comment: You might check https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures, it explains things from the start up and contains well written examples.

Comment: Also check my answer below, I changed all variable declarations to their correct form of let, var and const which gives you a good hint when to use what

Answer (score 2):

The army is an array of closures. Each closure print's the content of the variable `i`. But at the time that you execute the closure (e.g. when calling `army[5]()`) the while loop did already finish and thus `i` will always be 10. That is, because `i` was declared using the **var** keyword and thus the scope of `i` is the `makeArmy()` function. This is why `army[0]()` and `army[5]()` both print 10.

The code below is what you aim for:
Now `i` is passed into a **let** variable `x` and because the let keyword is used instead of var, the scope of `x` now is the individual shooter closure for that particular i-th iteration instead of the makeArmy function.

```
function makeArmy () {
   var shooters = []                // <-- use var here
   var i = 0                        // <-- because they're simple variables
   while (i < 10) {
      let x = i                     // <-- use let here to make x a block-scoped local variable that is bound to the closure
      const shooter = function() {  // <-- use const here because you never change the shooter thus it's a simple constant
         console.log(x)
      }
      shooters.push(shooter)
      i++
    }
  return shooters
 }
```

More details, explainations and simple examples can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Comment: got this.
but why its calling army function with index number two times?
army[0]();
army[5]();

Comment: As I said, this cannot be answered, because there is no reason. It is completely up to you what you do with those shooters in the army array. At the moment you created an array of callable shooters (your army). Now you can execute each of these 10 shooters by so army[n]() will execute the n-th shooter. SO you execute shooter 0 and 5. But why is to repeat myself all up to you and belongs to you're game's logic ;)